# Index out of range error in Python

Tags: python, indexing

I keep getting an error saying 'list index out of range' for my change_array[i] += 0 and change_array[i] += roc. I've also tried just using a '=' and that doesn't work either.

```
   #define variables for a loop
   change_array = []
   roc = 0

   #iterate to find the change percentage
   for i in range (0, end_year_index+1):
       if i == 0:
          change_array[i] += 0
       else:
           roc = ((population[i] - population[i-1])/ (population[i-1]))
           change_array[i] += roc
```

Comment: I think `change_array` should be `[0 for _ in range(end_year_index+1)]`, if you want there to be a zero to add to at each index. You can't index arbitrarily into a Python list, or at all with an empty list.

Comment: Curiously enough you could probably do what you wanted by just making `change_array` a dictionary.

Comment: @JeremyKemball a `defaultdict(int)`, certainly.

Comment: what do you expect `change_array` to contain initially as you have not defined it in the code above?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to add elements to `change_array`, if so, you need to use `change_array.append(your_element)`.

Comment: answers should not be based on assumptions. do let the OP ask a clear question first.

Answer (score 0):

`change_array = []` is an empty array, therefore there is no `0` element. `0` element is the first element in arrays.

```
array = ["one", "two"]
```

`array[0]` is "one", `array[1]` is "two"

Answer (score 0):

@Ekinydre gave you a good solution, but I just wanted to elaborate on the error you got.

When you have a list like `change_array = [1, 2, 3]`, then `change_array[i]` accessed element `i` (lists use 0-based indices in Python). Also, `+=` in Python is not an append operator, but an increment operator. So `change_array[i] += 10` you are adding `10` to the list element at position `i`.

You could just `append` to `change_array` as @Ekinydre suggests, but given your code it may be safer (though less pythonic) to do something like the following:

```
#define variables for a loop
#create a list of 0 of length end_year_index
change_array = [0]*end_year_index
roc = 0

#iterate to find the change percentage
for i in range (0, end_year_index+1):
    if i == 0:
       change_array[i] += 0
    else:
        roc = ((population[i] - population[i-1])/ (population[i-1]))
        change_array[i] += roc
```

A slightly more pythonic way could look like this:

```
change_array = [(population[i] - population[i-1]) / population[i-1] \
                    for i in range(1, end_year_index+1)]
```

Note: this last solution won't have the initial 0 at the beginning of `change_array`.